# Instantiate a class that sits in a workbook from XLA add-in

Tags: excel, vba, class

I have a class that I have defined in a workbook and I have an add-in installed already. I want to create an instance of that class from inside a module that is in the add-in without wiring the two from Tools/References. I want to do that purely with VBA, is there anyway to do that?

Comment: The problem is how are you going to define the class object in Add-In Module? I tried DIM obj as VBProjectName.clsMyClass, but it does not work. Keep in mind that I have to extract VBProject object programmatically too.

Comment: Tim solved it: the trick is to do DIM obj and not DIM obj as clsMyClass etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function in your WB which returns an instance of the class, and use Application.Run from the add-in to call it.

Simple example:

**ObjectSource.xlsm**

Class module *clsTest*:

```
Public MyNumber As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    MyNumber = 999
End Sub
```

Regular module:

```
Public Function GetObject() As Object
    Set GetObject = New clsTest
End Function
```

**Other workbook**

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim obj
    Set obj = Application.Run("ObjectSource.xlsm!GetObject")
    MsgBox obj.MyNumber ''>> 999
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, that answered my question, just Application.Run syntax should be:  Set obj = Application.Run("'ObjectSource.xlsm'!GetObject")